# Can you instantiate an Apps Script File object from Google API JSON response?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to do something like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(urlFetch.getContentText());
var entry = json.feed.entry;

for(var i in entry){
  if(userEmail == entry[i].getOwner()){
      //Do Stuff
  }
}
```

Assuming each **entry** here is a `File` in JSON retrieved from a call to `DocsList` feed, how can I hydrate it into an Apps Script `File` object so I can call normal `File` functions on it, like `getOwner()` or `getFileType()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may analyze the each entry by looking on the json string. I beleive you are using Google Docs native API,
After looking on the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_a_list_of_documents_and_files), I can see 
`entry.author.email` will give you author's email address.

Similarly, author's name: `entry.author.name`

You will not be having any method like `getOwner()` in that returned json.

Also, FYI, there is [DocslList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_docslist) service in Apps Script, which has such methods

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  I'm aware that you can dig through the JSON, but I'd rather be able to deserialize the object into a proper Apps Script File object to be able to call the documented functions on it.  I feel like I'm re-inventing the wheel writing functions to parse the JSON.